# I have to issue a second GET request to get the response I want

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

The first time I send a `GET` request to this endpoint the response is:
`allEvents = []`. If I wait a couple seconds and hit the endpoint again, I receive (the desired results) a populated `allEvents` array. So it is not working properly when first fired.

Notice the line `console.log(I am inside the function)`. This only appears a couple of seconds after I hit the endpoint for the first time.

How do I ensure this function is executed when the API endpoint is hit the first time?

```
var request = require('request');

var allEvents = [];

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    console.log("INSIDE MODULE ___ BEFORE FUNCTION");

    (function goToEB(){
        request({
            url: process.env.MY_OWNED_EVENTS,
            method: 'GET'
            }, function(error, response, body){
                console.log("INSIDE FUNCTIONNNNNN");
                if (error) {
                    return console.log(error);
                } else {
                    var data = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    var events = data.events;

                    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                        var event = {
                          name: events[i].name.text,
                          description: events[i].description.text,
                          id: events[i].id,
                          url: events[i].url,
                          start: events[i].start.local,
                          end: events[i].end.local
                      }
                      if (!eventDoesExist(event, allEvents)) {
                        allEvents.push(event);
                      } else {
                        console.log("EVENT EXISTS");
                      }
                    };
                    return allEvents;
                }
        })
    })();

    function eventDoesExist(obj, list) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] === obj) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

        res.send(allEvents);

}
```

Comment: In app.js:
`var events = require('./routes/events');`
`app.get('/api/events', events);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending your response before the second request returns any data and `allEvents` is populated. Move

```
res.send(allEvents);
```

Into the callback of your request like this:

```
                ...
                for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                    var event = {
                      name: events[i].name.text,
                      description: events[i].description.text,
                      id: events[i].id,
                      url: events[i].url,
                      start: events[i].start.local,
                      end: events[i].end.local
                  }
                  if (!eventDoesExist(event, allEvents)) {
                    allEvents.push(event);
                  } else {
                    console.log("EVENT EXISTS");
                  }
                };

                res.send(allEvents);
                ....
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I over looked that. Thanks!